# unknown data type return from KDB+ -79

Tags: kdb

i am facing a very strange problem in KDB+. where data type returned from kdb+ server is -79. that i can't find out.

does any body know that type is it. ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

79h is type for mapped list of lists of GUID data type.

Reference: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/datatypes/
Section: Nested Type.

From page:

**Nested Type:**

These types are used for mapped lists of lists of the same type. The numbering is 77 + primitive type.

Guid type is 2 which gives it's nested type value=79

ex:

```
      q)`:t1.dat set  2 2#0x0 sv 16?0xff
      q)  a:get `:t1.dat
      q) type a
      q) 79h
```